# Declaring attributes of a Javascript class?

Tags: javascript, class, oop, attributes

I know in Java I can declare a class with attributes and methods like so:

```
public class Foo {
     private int bar;

     public Foo() {
          bar = 286;
     }

     public int incrementBar() {
          bar += 100;
     }
}
```

Can I do something similar as far as declaring attributes in JavaScript?  If so, how?

Comment: You can use [class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Class_fields) to achieve this. These are currently in stage 3 so be mindful of browser support. Otherwise, you can use babel to transpile it or use something like typescript

Comment: Come on, it takes a few seconds to google the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: I did google the docs, and they were a bit confusing.  And given what I know now, it's looking like JavaScript might not be the right language for this project.  Thank you both for your help!

Comment: JavaScript doesn't really have classes, it has flexible objects and prototype inheritance. It also doesn't have private fields, or at least not quite yet. It's not that the language has less features, it is simply designed around very different principles. An introductory course on JavaScript would explain all this, which is why your question was deemed low quality by some users. People aren't likely to put an effort writing an answer you might not even understand because you haven't done your homework ;) But if you want a classical language that isn't Java, I'd recommend looking at C#.

Comment: @Domino , thanks.  I did decide to use C# for this project, and your comment really helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent would be this.

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.bar = 289;
    }

    incrementBar() {
        this.bar += 100;
    }
}
```

You can declare the variable bar on the class aswell, but it will not be private, and also it's not needed.